# How can I write a batch file that numbers files with a particular extension, and if the count is over 10, deletes all but the latest

Tags: batch-file

I have a program that pull stat files (`*.csv`) into a directory, parses them for particular data, puts that data in a database, and renames the file (`.csv.med`).  Sometimes this does not work and `.csv` files begin accumulating while system resources are pegged.

What I am trying to do is write a batch file which checks the number of `.csv` files and, if that number is greater than ten, deletes all but the most recent one.

I am using the following command to delete all but the most recent, but need a way to tie that in with a command that numbers the files.

```
for /f "skip=1 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir *.csv /b /o-d /tw /a-d') do @del "%%F
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /f %%G IN ('dir *.csv /b ^|FIND /c "."') DO IF %%G gtr 13 (
 for /f "skip=1 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir *.csv /b /o-d /tw /a-d') do ECHO del "%%F"
)
```

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files. The `@` is not required.

I've used `13` as my trigger point because that suits my system. You'd use 10.

Essentially, perform a `dir` listing using basic format of the target filemask, then count the number of lines containing `.` and assign that number to `%%G`. If `%%G` is greater than the requirement, delete the files.

(I've presumed that you mean "Count" the files, not "number" them)

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  And yes, I should have said "count," not "number."

What would I do if I wanted to also delete all the `.csv.med` files if more than 10 `.csv` files were found?

Comment: Modify `ECHO del "%%F"` to `ECHO del "%%F" "*.csv.mod" 2>nul"` **DEL** can take multiple arguments. On the first deletion, all of the `.csv.mod` files would be deleted. The `2>nul` would suppress error messages.